# how to get one's distribution group of lync

Tags: exchange-server, lync

there is a tab in lync named 'Membership', aka 'Distribution Group'.
How to enum one contact's all distribution groups?
I do did googles and read all docs of lync sdk, not found any way to achieve it.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: I write a console program so power shell scripts is not preferred, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This data isnt held inside Lync. I assume, you have Exchange running too? Lync gets this Information from there. You can get it similiar like this:

```
$groups = Get-DistributionGroup
$groups | where-object { ( Get-DistributionGroupMember $_ | where-object { $_.Name -eq $user}) }
```

**Limitation:** it will gets you only Groups with direct Membership, not the recurse look like on the lync card.

Comment: Any hint about pure C# code? I write a console program in fact, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, Im not a C# developer, so i posted Powershell. You could find a starting point here, as Exchange (Distribution)Groups are AD Groups: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180906(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "corp domain host");
var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, name);

var userEntry = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
```

then `userEntity.Properties["memberOf"] as object[]` is an array of strings, which presents DistinguishedName of employees